# Syslog-NG: Possible to disable "keep_hostname" but enable for a specific filter?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

Was wondering if this was possible at all.  I am currently facing a situation where I have a legacy NG system with a number of sources integrated.  We are working to slowly transition off of this particular instance, but to do this I need to make sure that the messages that are emitted retain their source host.

Unfortunately, when this legacy environment was crafted, the `keep_hostname` option was set to false, which meant that the engineers focused on source log specific `HOST` extraction.

As I am working to tee the data off to the new system, I need the data to retain its source hostname.  Ideally one would just flip `keep_hostname` to `yes`, but there is too much risk right now as it could impact how data is being parsed throughout the system.

My ask is, while `keep_hostname` is globally disabled, is there a way that I can enable it within a `filter` or `destination`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with a globally disabled `keep-hostname()` option is not really possible as the original host information is lost.

When `keep-hostname(no)` is used, a feature called "store-raw-message" can be enabled which stores the entire incoming message in the `$RAWMSG` macro. The raw message definitely contains the original hostname, but then it is up to you to extract the host from the whole message.

---

> My ask is, while keep_hostname is globally disabled, is there a way that I can enable it within a filter or destination?

You can achieve something similar the other way around:
Setting `keep-hostname()` to `yes` keeps the original host name intact, but you will have 2 different macros:

- `$HOST` contains the original hostname
- `$HOST_FROM` contains the "source's" hostname

Applying a rewrite rule which overrides $HOST with $HOST_FROM can be added to paths where you want to retain the old behavior.

Comment: WOW. Ok. Just wanted to acknowledge that i saw this answer and I'm excited to try it tomorrow morning.  Will report back and accept on confirmation.  Thank you!!